# occure exception crystal report when install on client machin

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, crystal-reports

I have written an application and I used Crystal Report for reporting . when I install on client PC ... exception occurred when report was generating

i guess may be my CrystalReport Runtime has problem.I installed **"CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_12"**

**Exception Information :**

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: Test.exe

Problem Signature 02: 0.60.0.89

Problem Signature 03: 54a7ef37

Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework

Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209

Problem Signature 06: 5348b261

Problem Signature 07: 67e5

Problem Signature 08: 13

Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentNullException

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1065
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Client spec : Windows 7 32bit

What should I do?

Comment: You've got to love the PoS that is Crystal... have a read of http://www.sevenforums.com/software/323079-program-has-stopped-working-problem-event-name-clr20r3.html

Comment: Is the XNA Framework installed on the host machine?

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/software/323079-program-has-stopped-working-problem-event-name-clr20r3.html  -> this problem is diffrent my problem is "System.ArgumentNullException" but your link about "System.TypeInitialization" both of them are same ?

Comment: From what I've read  CLR20r3 is the common element... the only fix I've seen is where people say a repair of .net 2 fixes things... don't quote me on that though.